# How to prevent MITM DNS attack by router

Tags: wifi, man-in-the-middle, dns, router

My landlord is very much a busybody and he has extreme political views. I suspect he is using a Windows program that communicates with the Wifi router to record what websites all the tenants are visiting. I suspect this not just because of his personality but because (A) the Wifi router is insisting on being the DNS, and (B) when his Windows computer got ruined by the recent Windows 10 update bug, he was forced to change the two SSIDs of the Wifi router. Normally SSIDs never need to be changed because of what happens on any connected computer.

My simple workaround to the router wanting to be my DNS was always to use 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8 and 9.9.9.9 as my DNSes. However if his Wifi router has the ability to be a DNS MITM and it e.g. knows that these IPs are well-known DNSes, then it could still be recording all my DNS interactions. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's only DNS you're worried about, then just use DNS-over-TLS or DNS-over-HTTPS. However, if you're worried about this, then you should probably be worried about the rest of your traffic too, so I'd recommend you use a VPN.

Comment: Agreed: VPN is the way to go.